# how to turn on the android phone screen at the desired time in new APIs (above API 23)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wake-lock, powermanager

I am developing a new application that is needed to light up the screen at the desired time and play a sound or alarm along with the notification.
this concept is working in APIs below 23 with **Wake_lock** and some other deprecated methods. but as I mentioned most of them has been deprecated in new APIs due to some power-saving strategy which is called ***DOZE*** mode.

there are too many available apps which are working in the same way which I asked. but I did not find any good help or clue for my question.

is there any solution for the above issue (**turning on the screen at the desired time**)?

Comment: If this is an alarm clock app, use `setAlarmClock()` on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Thanks,
No, it is not an alarm. I have another target. by alarm manager, it is not possible to wake up the phone and turn on the screen!! in Doze mode there is too many restrictions  .